# Apache Avro generates wrong Avro schema from Java POJO with @AvroSchema

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, avro

I have a simple POJO with dates, that will be stored as Avro in storage before imported into Google BigQuery. Dates are converted to long, and I'm trying to use @AvroSchema to override the schema generation for the date fields so that BigQuery understands which type the fields are.

The simple POJO:

```
public class SomeAvroMessage implements Serializable {
    @AvroSchema("{\"type\":\"long\",\"logicalType\":\"timestamp-millis\"}")
    private long tm;
    @AvroSchema("{\"type\":\"long\",\"logicalType\":\"timestamp-millis\"}")
    private long created;

    public SomeAvroMessage() {
    }
}
```

This ends up with the following AVRO-schema:

```
{"type":"record","name":"SomeAvroMessage",
"namespace":"some.namespace",
"fields":[
      {"name":"tm","type":{"type":"long","logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}},
      {"name":"created","type":{"type":"long","logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}}
]}
```

These seems to be wrong, and should be simply *{"name":"tm","type":"long","logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}*

This is used in Google Dataflow, with Apache Beam 2.22 written in Java.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What makes you think its wrong? The schema is a valid schema

Comment: Yes, this is a valid schema, per my answer. But is it causing a problem in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value `{"name":"tm","type":{"type":"long","logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}}` is correct. If we expand it to more clear pseudocode, it is:

```
Field {
  name: "tm",
  type: Schema {
    type: "long",
    logicalType: "timestamp-millis"
  }
}
```

You can see that the field has a `name` and a `type`. The `type` of an Avro field must be an Avro schema. The `logicalType` field goes inside the schema, not adjacent to it.

Comment: Thanks guys, seems I did not read specs good enough!

Answer (score 0):

As can be found in the [documentation](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html):

> A logical type is an Avro primitive or complex type with extra
> attributes to represent a derived type. The attribute logicalType must
> always be present for a logical type, and is a string with the name of
> one of the logical types listed later in this section. Other
> attributes may be defined for particular logical types.

The documentation also gives an example of date type in avro schemas:

```
{
  "type": "int",
  "logicalType": "date"
}
```

Basically your schema is correct and everytime you need to use some Logical Type you can build your schema like this.